# Method works on local but fails on Ropsten

Tags: transactions, ropsten, gas-estimate, revert-opcode

Trying to debug this transaction (it's a large one that deploys a contract) that works on local but fails on ropsten.

First, it said

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}, method="estimateGas"
```

When I add a `gasLimit` the transaction processes but reverts. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe48dd4ac0543285fa86a6e1b1a1f23c55004b35d9f5c238057f291840f629331

What's going on? What's a good way to debug something like this?

Comment: You most likely have an error in your constructor. Since it’s working on a local blockchain (forked?) but not on Ropsten, Do you, for instance, have some other pre-existing contracts you’re interacting with?

Comment: Thanks @DrGorilla.eth!

I tried to debug it by verifying the contract on tenderly and in the process realised I was reading the contract address from the wrong environment ><

Problem solved~~

For others looking to debug you can try this: https://tenderly.co/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to debug it by verifying the contract on tenderly and in the process realised I was reading the contract address from the wrong environment >< Problem solved~~ For others looking to debug you can try this: tenderly.co

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean with "wrong environment"? Tenderly by itself won't solve things it is just a tool.